# PayPal buttons overlapping site elements - can't control positioning due to inline CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, paypal, magento2

I have integrated PayPal buttons on my Magento website but these buttons get their CSS classes inline and always overlap other elements when scrolling.

For example, on the site's fixed header, the PayPal button overlays it when scrolling down. I've tried playing with positioning, z-index, etc. but I've only managed to change the button's size.

Since the styles are inline, I can't modify its natural position on the page. Is there any way or trick to force the PayPal button to be positioned naturally in the page flow?

Any suggestions or help to resolve this overlapping issue is appreciated, as the buttons are interfering with other key site elements. Thanks!

[ScreenShot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWsqL.png)

Comment: give the container the buttons render in the size / css position you want and place it anywhere

Answer (score 0):

1. Change z-index in header to make it bigger than z-index in paypal block
2. Wrap paypal block in a div and give it z-index to make it less than  z-index  in header.